# Preventing user access to the sub-folders of an app?

Tags: php, security, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Looking some frameworks like Code Igniter I see they use a "defined" check on the syspath to prevent users opening the files from the subfolders, and also an index.html placed on every folder. 
Can't I just use a mod_rewrite and get rid of these checks? 
Is the mod_rewrite enough to let the users access only the index.php of the entire application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move all the files for your application out of the web root and only have those files there that should be accessible by users.

Comment: this is the best way. Then use mod_rewrite to send every request through the index.php file (front controller).

Comment: Wouldn't be enough to send all the requests to the index via mod_rewrite? Is there a way to hack that and view all the stuff?

Comment: @eij: In theory, in a perfect world, yes it is enough. However in theory in an imperfect world your web browser may have bugs that allows such hacks to happen. In practice we assume the world is imperfect.

Answer (score 0):

Place all non-accessible files in folders and then put a new .htaccess file in each folder containing:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
```

This will prevent HTTP access to those folders in Apache (other servers will have equiv. options). We use this to prevent access to `incldue/`, which contains the libs, static config etc.